# DataGrid CellTemplate multiple properties

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, properties, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a CellTemplate where I create columns dynamically via PropertyDescriptors. I'm using this approach: http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid Column generation works, and the correct content reaches the correct cell.

My problem lies when i changes the content provided to the cell from ex. 'string' or 'int' to a custom class containing multiple properties. The CellTemplate wont bind to the properties within the contentclass.

The Content class:

```
    public class ContentWrapper
    {
        public Color Color{ get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
        public String Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

The cellTemplate:

```
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid ToolTip="{Binding Comment}"
                              Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>                                                                
                            <Polygon Visibility="{Binding Comment, Converter={StaticResource CommentVisibleConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                     Points="0,0 6,0 6,6"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Polygon.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                                </Polygon.Fill>
                            </Polygon>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

How do i make the CellTemplate able to support a custom class and bind to it's properties?
Or is there a more easy way?

**EDIT**
The Column generation is this:

```
    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var property = e.PropertyDescriptor as Property;
        if (property != null)
        {
            var binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(property), Mode = property.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay };
            var dataGridBoundColumn = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
            if (dataGridBoundColumn != null)
                dataGridBoundColumn.Binding = binding;
            else
            {
                var dataGridComboBoxColumn = e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn;
                if (dataGridComboBoxColumn != null)
                    dataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItemBinding = binding;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh.. been working on this for 2 days, and 1 hour after asking I solve the problem.

I Changed the Column type was to a nested type of DataGridTemplateColumn with manually load of cell template and binding.

Answer (score 1):

Well done for fixing your problem.

> I am not attempting to answer your question, instead simply offering some advice:

You *seem* to be trying to `Bind` to your data instance properties from inside the `DataGrid ControlTemplate`... that's not really what that is for. The `Template` property allows us to define how the control looks. You should put your item `Style` and data `Binding` in the `ItemsTemplate` which defines how the data items are rendered. This is an important distinction.

From MSDN:

> ItemsTemplate Property - Gets or sets the DataTemplate used to display each item.
>
> Template Property - Gets or sets a control template. The ControlTemplate specifies the appearance of a Control

Comment: Thank you for the response. To be able to bind to the collection i had to use a DataTemplate, so this issue solved itself.